# C++ calling constructor to initialize an object yields errors

Tags: c++, constructor

What's wrong with this:

```
struct FileListItem {
    string  sOriginalFn;
    time_t  ttTimeTaken;

    FileListItem(){}
    FileListItem(string _sOriginalFn, time_t _ttTimeTaken) :
        sOriginalFn (_sOriginalFn), ttTimeTaken (_ttTimeTaken)  { }
};

struct FileList : vector<FileListItem> {
    int iCurItm;
    FileList() : vector(), iCurItm(-1) {};

    void Add(string _sOriginalFn, time_t _ttTimeTaken) { 
        push_back(FileListItem(_sOriginalFn, _ttTimeTaken)); 
    }
}
```

I get a run-time `"read access violation"` the first time `Add` is called.

I then try:

```
struct FileList : vector<FileListItem> {
    int iCurItm;
    FileList() : vector(), iCurItm(-1) {};

    FileListItem Itm;                    // <--- new member
    void Add(string _sOriginalFn, time_t _ttTimeTaken) { 
        Itm(_sOriginalFn, _ttTimeTaken); // <--- E0980 pointing to "Itm"
        push_back(Itm); 
    }
}
```

and get a compile time error:

`E0980 - call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type.`

I must have forgotten or missed something since I stopped programming 30 years ago, when Borland C++ was IT...

Comment: It is usually considered bad practice to inherit from the standard library. It's better to have a struct containing a vector than to inherit from `std::vector`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong, you can access `push_back` even with private inheritance from within you derived class. Note that there is a typo in `FileList() : vector(), iCurItm(-1) {};`, the semicolon is superfluous at the end.

Comment: VS2017 did not give any runtime error when `Add` was called. what is your compiler?

Comment: Using VS2017.  I eliminated `, iCurItm(-1)`. and eliminated the superfluous `;` typo. And still - getting the same runtime error.
miradham - can you show the full program you used to test it - maybe it's something about the way I first create or call my objects?

Comment: @Itay1 Please refer to the code in my answer.

Comment: We need a full reproducible example of the code being run in order to understand where that error is coming from

Comment: Got it! your code @miradham worked fine. What caused the stubborn memory over-run (and took me a few hours to figure out) was that `Add` was called elsewhere in the program (similar to what @Rerito suggested in his/her answer) through `FileList &FL;`, which once using `*FL` - made it all go away. 
I must have done something TERRIBLE using `&` in this context..! though I wonder, with the thousands of compiler/linker errors and warnings, how this was only caught at run time. _thanks all for helping_.

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like a dangling reference. I'm sure you replaced it by a pointer with dynamic allocation (IOW `new FileList(...)`)

Comment: actually no, it is a pointer (and was a &ref) to the `FileList` already allocated when declared `FileList fl;` inside `main()`. I hope at least I got that part right..! I am realizing quite painfully that these innocent-looking "+" signs after "C" have actually taken over and what's left is barely a souvenir of C... for a veteran/newbie like myself trying to debug `a = b;` is a most terrifying experience!

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
Itm(_sOriginalFn, _ttTimeTaken);
```

You are not calling the constructor for your object. Instead, the compiler interprets this as a function call on the functor `Itm`. Therefore, it tries to find a valid `operator()` for the given arguments, to no-avail.

Do not use constructor member initializer list syntax elsewhere than... Constructor member initializer list. Instead, what you have to do here is to assign a new object to your member.

Then, you don't want, ever to inherit from `std` containers. Their destructor is not virtual so you are exposing yourself to a realm of suffering...

Use composition or type aliasing instead:

```
struct FileList {
    std::vector<FileListItem> flist;
    int curItem;

    FileList() : flist(), curItem(-1) {}

    void Add(string const& _sOriginalFn, time_t _ttTimeTaken) {
    // No need to construct the object before, let vector handle it
    flist.emplace_back(_sOriginalFn, _ttTimeTaken);
};
```

As for the read access violation, from the code I see, nothing explains it. Could it be some access related to `curItem` somewhere in your code that isn't displayed here?

Comment: this does not explain `read access violation` OP has faced first

Comment: Just note that this will copy from rvalue arguments.

Comment: @DanielLangr indeed. I didn't want to overcomplicate things with a perfect forwarding design

Comment: I eliminated `iCurItm` from the constructor, and also eliminated the entire constructor - runtime error is **exactly** the same. Any ideas?
@miradham - can you show the full program you used to test it - maybe it's something about the way I first create or call my objects?

Comment: OK, Got it! @miradham's code ran OK, but the stubborn memory over-run continued as long as `FileList.Add` was (elsewhere in the code, as @Retiro suggested) invoked through a local variable defined: `FileList &FL;`. Once it changed to `FileList *FL;` - There was no problem. I must have done something absolutely TERRIBLE! though I wonder how, with thousands of compiler errors/warnings, this was not caught. Thanks everybody for help and advice!